# Javascript: Event listeners for windows media player in IE11

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, addeventlistener, windows-media-player, attachevent

I have come across an issue in the code base I working with in IE11 specifically.

Other versions of IE allow me to listen to a specific event called 'OpenStateChanged' which is fired from Windows Media Player like so.

```
document.getElementById('video-player').attachEvent("OpenStateChanged",
                    (newState) =>
                )
```

When running the code in IE11, I am getting the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'` which I understand as it is no longer supported.  So I have modified my code to check if you can use the newer `addEventListener`.

```
if (document.getElementById('video-player').addEventListener) 
                document.getElementById('video-player').addEventListener("OpenStateChanged",
                    (newState) =>
                        console.log newState
                        #MediaOpen state
                        if newState == 13
                            //do stuff
                )
else
    document.getElementById('video-player').attachEvent("OpenStateChanged",
        (newState) =>
            #MediaOpen state
            if newState == 13
                //do stuff
         )
```

This is alright, and it runs without throwing errors, however, the event handler function is never fired.  I have noticed that things like `onclick` get changed to `click`, but I have seen no documentation on event names for Windows Media Player.

Syntax in coffeescript,  can provide js alternative if required.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811810/events-not-firing-on-wmp-object-in-ie11#  - looks like its an active bug...